# C++: Sending a struct memberwise

Tags: c++, memory, structure, member

I want to send a struct sMessage byte by byte from one microcontroller to another:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    unsigned char mu8MessageId; 
    unsigned char mu8MessageSenderId; 
    unsigned char mu8MessageReceiverId; 
    unsigned short mu16MessageSizePayload; 
    unsigned short mu16MessageSizeTotal;
} sMessage;

sMessage msMessage;
```

Therefore I use a simple function

```cpp
MSGSENDER_vSend(void* pvMessage, unsigned short u16Size)
```

which takes a void poiner and the size of the data to be sent. At the receiver I receive the sent data byte by byte, and reconstructs the sent data out of it. I have the same byte order on both devices.
Unfortunately I receive the bytes in a different order if I

- call this function once with the struct msMessage and its size as parameters (byte order seems to be right)

```cpp
MSGSENDER_vSend(&msMessage, sizeof(msMessage))
```

- call this function for every member of the struct (byte order is not correct)

```cpp
MSGSENDER_vSend(&msMessage.mu8MessageId, sizeof(msMessage.mu8MessageId))
MSGSENDER_vSend(&msMessage.mu8MessageSenderId, sizeof(msMessage.mu8MessageSenderId))
//...
```

Why are the bytes sent in a different order?

Comment: How do you *receive* the data? Memberwise or full structure? And you have the same byte-order on both sending and receiving side? And the packing of the structure is the same?

Comment: Oh, and I assume that in your real code, you don't mix the type-alias `sMessage` with variables named `sMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the compiler and the compile flags, there can be "gaps" between the members in the struct. If it optimizes for speed, there is a chance that it will try to align the members according to the largest member type.
In your case you are using 3 1-byte members and 2 2-byte members and may insert 1 byte of void between the last char and the first short so the short is aligned by two (since it's 2 bytes)

Anyway, you should never send (or store) raw structs since they can change if you recompile the application with different flags. The safest way is always to send the data members one by one, then you have full control of the order on the receiving side

Comment: I see. So using the packed attribute (or similar attributes depending on the compiler) should fix this issue?

Comment: Well yes, it probably will, but still, it is not good practice to send structs, you should serialize the data in a controlled way.